# installing dspace on windows

Tags: tomcat, dspace

I am trying to install [DSpace](http://www.dspace.org/) on Windows. I have installed all the supporting software required.

As per the instructions given at http://casin.ncsi.iisc.ernet.in/dspace/dspacewindows.htm, to install DSpace I am supposed to copy the `dspace.war` and `dspace-oai.war` from the folder `C:\Dspace\build` to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps`.

However I cannot find those two files and even the folder is not present - can anyone sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation misses that you have to install Tomcat5.5 before!

And the war files get build in process if you call the ant command (which you have to install and place it on the PATH, too, IMHO, without them saying that).